# "Could not find endpoint element with name..."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wcf, app-config

Sorry for the long problem statement...I've spent two days debugging and have a lot of notes...

I have a WCF data service and another process trying to connect to it as a client via TCP and/or HTTP.

I have a VERY simple test client app that seems to connect fine, but the more complicated production app cannot connect (neither TCP or HTTP).  In both client projects, I let Visual Studio 2008 generate the app.config by using "Add Service Reference" and letting it pull metadata from the data service.

Here is the code for the simple test client that works:

```
using Client.MyDataService;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDataServiceClient client = new MyDataServiceClient("net.tcp");

            client.GetRecords();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the more complicated, production client:

DataServiceManager.cs:

```
using MyServer.MyDataService;

namespace MyServer.DataServiceBridge
{
    class DataServiceManager
    {
        MyDataServiceClient dataServiceClient = new MyDataServiceClient("net.tcp");
}
}
```

In main process:

```
DataServiceManager d = new DataServiceManager();
```

Here is the app.config file for both simple client and production client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="net.tcp" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
                    transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8888/MyDataService"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="net.tcp" contract="MyDataService.IMyDataService"
                name="net.tcp">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="COMPUTER_NAME\Username" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

- In MyServer's bin\Debug\ folder is
  MyServer.exe, app.config.
- In MyDataSeriviceHost's bin\Debug\
  folder is MyDataService.exe,
  app.config, and
  MyDataSeriviceHost.exe.config.
  app.config and
  MyDataSeriviceHost.exe.config are
  identical.

Here is the error message:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll but 
was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find endpoint element with name 'net.tcp' and contract
 'MyDataService.IMyDataService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.
 This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint
 element matching this name could be found in the client element.
```

Any ideas what is going on?  I've pretty much exhausted Google. :-(

Comment: Probably a typo, but your error message reads: IyDataService. Should probably be IMyDataService.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo in redacting for posting here.  Fixed, thanks!

Comment: please don't duplicate tags like "WCF" in the title. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @CrypticPrime: Please can you leave the original un-redacted version in future, if it is what one of the causes of the error? I was searching for IyDataService and couldn't see it anywhere, which was exactly my problem, but the upvoted comment didn't match your question's content. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SOLVED

It turns out that we have an exe that loads a DLL.
The DLL contains the WCF client.
When compiled, MyServer.dll.config is generated, but since the exe is native (not .NET) it does not read in a .config file automatically.  We need to do it manually.
This link allowed me to load the config manually and create a CustomChannelFactory<> to solve this question.

For anybody else needing the same thing, here is the link that led to the solution:
http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/11/26/reading-wcf-configuration-from-a-custom-location.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I had a situation like this, where i had

- WCF Service Hosted somewhere
- Main Project
- Consumer Project of type 'class Library' which has Service reference to a WCF Service
- Main project calls methods from consumer project

Now the Consumer project had all the related configuration setting in `<system.serviceModel>` Tag of my app.config, its was still throwing the same error as the above.

All i did is added the same tag `<system.serviceModel>` to my main project's app.config file, and finally we were good to go.

The Real problem, as far as in my case was, it was reading the wrong configuration file. Instead of consumer's app.config, it was referring main proj's config. it took me two hours to figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

Could be just the way you wrote it up but it sounds like your config file is not being copied to the directory correctly. It should have a matching name to your application not app.config. If you try changing the name of the app.config file to [your exe name].exe.config does that help.

Comment: I tried that as well.  It does not work.  Both app.config and MyServer.exe.config are in there (and I tried removing one or the other too just for kicks).

Comment: Well just for future reference app.config will never work because it won't get picked up. So both applications have the .config file in there with the name matching the name of the current exe. Did you maybe copy the config from the simple app into the complex app and forget to change the name of the config?

Comment: Sadly, I wish this were the case. All file names are correct.

Comment: Hrmmm...I just noticed that VS is generating MyServer.dll.config and not a *.exe.config file.  Is this a problem? Is there some magic I need to do with a DLL?

Comment: Yes, I see this is not a direct relationship to the simple client that works.  The big production app has a BigServer.exe app that loads in all of our code that is compiled into MyServer.dll.  Perhaps this should be a separate question on StackOverflow?

Comment: +1 My problem was different, but this led me to the solution.  Somehow, perhaps because I changed my build configuration from Any CPU to x86, my output files were not being copied to the correct directory, hence, no App.Config.

Comment: @TonyD Glad it could help out even if it wasn't the same situation.

Comment: A simple test solution with 1 project will have the .exe.config Whereas I had an exe in a more complicated solution and needed the post build events to copy the .exe.config file.

Answer (score 3):

When the EXE consumes the DLL the config file it looks for is not DLLName.Dll.Config its EXEName.exe.config , change the name of the generated config file and copy it to the execution path. It should work.

Cheers!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

A similar situation with different solution that may be of use in these particular circumstances:

- Like the above posts, I have an EXE hosting Client defined in DLL.
- Different to above situation is that my Client is using UDP probe to
  discover Service endpoints (obviously service has MEX enabled)

The ClientProxy inherits [DuplexClientBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574957(v=vs.110).aspx), and overloaded instantiation method allows you to specify binding and endpoint without requiring ANY config files.

A VB example, I have discovered an endpoint (ep) and I know the binding is TCP with security disabled, so I can instantiate and use callback client as:

```
myClientProxy = New ClientProxy(New InstanceContext(Me), New NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), ep.Address)
```