# .Net DLL config file with a twist

Tags: c#, java, .net, interop

I have a .Net 3.5 DLL that calls external web services. The code uses binding config options from the config file in system.serviceModel section. All works great when called from .net test app.

The issue occurs when I'm calling it from Java based system and the config file is not being found by the DLL.

Now, I was able to work around the issue for appSettings using this method: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/199441/DLL-with-configuration-file

However, I don't explicitly read the serviceModel section - the .Net does.

So, is there a way to "fool" .Net to find that config file?

Comment: Found this so far - seems to be the right solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188965/could-not-find-endpoint-element-with-name

Comment: if java.exe is the process it's running under, it might be looking for the config file as java.exe.config?

Comment: No, what I posted above worked - here is actually a better link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f33e620a-e332-4fd4-ae21-88c750437355/    all I had to do is copy paste the code