# Could not find endpoint element as referring to main project config settings

Tags: vb.net, wcf

Wonder if anyone can help me as i'm getting the following error 'Could not find endpoint element'.

My setup is similar to the following - A main project vb.net (Starts with say a login.exe that in turn uses class libraries to then do things such as set the menu navigation system which proceeds to call several winform class libraries) One of my winform class library calls another class library which contains some logic that will then in turn call a class library that has the service reference to a WCF service and will handle the WCF service reference function calls.

So if i run my winform as a standalone exe rather than a class library contained in the above setup everything works fine with connecting to the web service contained within the class libraries because i have added the `<system.serviceModel>` reference information to my winforms app.config as per the below thread suggested.

["Could not find endpoint element with name..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188965/could-not-find-endpoint-element-with-name)

My issue is that once i turn my winform back to a class library and include in my main project to be called it never finds the the `<system.serviceModel>` reference contained within my winform .dll as i'm lead to believe by again by the above linked post it will use the main project app.config not my winforms configuration.

What im trying to get at is I don't really want to add the `<system.serviceModel>` information contained in the app.config of my winform dll to the starting login.exe(being the program that starts the chain) as that just seems messy and just strikes me i must be doing somthing wrong in the first place. Is there a way to use the setting from my winform class rather than going all the back back through to the main project??.

I hope that makes some sort of sense any help would be greatly appreciated as really stuck as a wcf newbie, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't think it's messy, that is generally how these things are done there is an application configuration file for your main you only have one copy of your main and usually your application is installed only once meanwhile you could have lots of copies of your DLL used by many apps... The configuration file will usually always contain settings that pertain to that one application meanwhile a DLL could be used by multiple applications. In short you should use the main app.config.

In any case to answer your question you could read in the app.config of the DLL in like any normal file parse it and programmatically setup the end-points as described here:

[How to: Create a Service Endpoint in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731080%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)